# IP Address Class C network and its gateway

Tags: networking, ip-address, router, gateway, subnet

Suppose I have following network setup, in a ethernet:

1. I manually setup start IP and end IP as following:
   `192.168.2.1 - 192.168.254.254`
2. Manually setup Gateway IP as:
   `192.168.2.1`
3. Of course, Mask length as:
   `16`
4. Subnet Mask:
   `255.255.0.0`

Now my question would be following:

1. Class C network should starting with range: `[128, 191]`, if I'm using `192.*.*.*` and setup subnet mask as `255.255.0.0`, does it work?
2. Is there any specific requirement to setup gateway in order to make sure range `192.168.2.1 - 192.168.254.254` work?
3. For any gateway that: `192.168.2.1 < gateway < 192.168.254.254`, it should work for the range?
4. Suppose within this ethernet, I manually change one's IP to `192.168.1.*`, does it able to ping gateway `(192.168.2.1)`?

Comment: Network classes are dead, killed in 1993 by RFCs 1518 and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networking does not use network classes, probably since before you were born. Please let them rest in peace.

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

1. Since only recently (i. e. about 20 years ago), classful networking is obsolete in favour of CIDR. So you can have an IP range in the old Class A which has a netmask length of 24 bit, or a range in the former Class C range with a netmask length of 16 (or maybe even 17, 18, whatever) bits.
2. You need a gateway if you want to communicate outside of your network.
3. The range is defined by the net mask. Even if you only want to use 192.168.2 to 192.168.254, there is no way to exclude 0, 1 and 255 as the third octet, so 192.168.1.* is perfectly reachable from your subnet.

Comment: "_Since only recently (i. e. about 20 years ago), classful networking is obsolete in favour of CIDR._" I'm not sure what you mean by recently. CIDR was defined in 1993, and the Internet didn't become commercially available until 1995. Removing network class restrictions was necessary in order to create the current public, commercial Internet, and there have been no network classes since.

Comment: @RonMaupin Ok, then it wasn't 20, but 24 years ago. Doesn't funtamentally change my statement. (Sarcasm and irony are known to you as concepts?)

Answer (score 0):

1. 192.168.0.0/24 is address of restricted private IP subset [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) It will work.
2. Gateway is rather term of specified host within network which has access to other networks. It's address must be accessible from network.
3. Yes. (Of course if physically connected)